tkinter canvas.delet('all') does not set the item count to 0
Root is my tk window and I'm using it's title to display debug data.
When I run this code the find_all keeps incrementing as if the items are still there but empty and not drawing on the screen.  is there a way to get this to reset to 0?
def draw_file(empty = ""):
   canvas.delete('all')
   canvas.create_line(10,10, 100, 100,arrow=tk.LAST)
   canvas.create_line(100,10, 100, 100,arrow=tk.LAST)
   root.title(canvas.find_all())

Expecting to have the item count set back to 0
Seems that setting the canvas back to 0 is not possible.  Below is my failed code for creating and destroying a canvas.
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter.filedialog import askopenfilename
import tkinter.scrolledtext as ScrolledText
from tkinter import messagebox
from functools import partial

class New_Canvas(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, master=None):
        super().__init__(master)
        self.master = master
        self.pack()
        self.create_widgets()

    def create_widgets(self):
        self.canvas = tk.Canvas(self)
        self.canvas.relief='ridge'
        self.canvas.bd = 2
        self.canvas.pack(side='top')
        self.button1 = tk.Button(self)
        self.button1["text"] = "Hello World\n(click me)"
        self.button1["command"] = self.say_hi
        self.button1.pack(side="top")

        self.button2 = tk.Button(self, text="QUIT", fg="red",
                              command=self.destroy)
        self.button2.pack(side="bottom")

    def say_hi(self):
        print("hi there, everyone!")

def canvas_new():
    app=New_Canvas(master=root)
    print('new')

def canvas_destroy():
    app.destroy()
    print('destroy')

root = tk.Tk()

button = tk.Button(master=root, text="Add", command=canvas_new)
button.pack()
button2 = tk.Button(master=root, text="remove", command=canvas_destroy)
button2.pack()

canvas_frame = tk.Frame(root, width =615, height = 500)
canvas_frame.pack(fill= tk.BOTH, expand = True)

root.mainloop()


The IDs of the canvas items isn't necessary a counter. tkinter doesn't reuse IDs because it might be hard to keep track of which ones can be reused and which ones can't. Why do you want to reset it to 0?

I was looking to draw lines and arcs on the canvas from data stored in list boxes.  I wanted to have the option to clear the list boxes and the canvas so they all start back at 0.  Based on these responses that will not be possible.  I have been experimenting with creating a new canvas with a button but I'm having trouble destroying the canvas.  I will give updated code in my question for my destroy attempt.

If you are looking to get the attributes/bounding boxes of the things on the canvas, there is a simpler way. All of the canvas create_* methods return the id of the newly created object which you can use.

canvas.delete("all") should delete all items, so item count (number of items) should be zero.  What is your issue on not able to reset item ID (not item count) to zero? Note also that item ID starts from 1, not zero.

@TheLizzard I found that I can use canvas.find("all") to get all of the active IDs but I had hoped that I could keep the numbering sequence of the canvas items and the list boxes the same.  Plus I didn't want to have a huge amount of dead canvas items.

@acw1668 I'm used to programming starting at 0 but you are correct this starts at 1, can you provide an example of how to get the count?  I'm thinking for loop, or is there a direct method?

As you said canvas.find_all() returns all active IDs, so len(canvas.find_all()) may be what you want to get the count.

The canvas doesn't recycle element ids. If you add ten elements, the ids will be the numbers 1-10. Whether you delete them all or not, the next element will get an id of 11.
This is mentioned in the official canvas man page, in the section titled Canvas IDs and Tags where it states (emphasis added by me):

The id of an item never changes and id numbers are never re-used within the lifetime of a canvas widget.

